# Create CloudPages webpage using API or AppExchange

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi

Using the Content Builder API I have been able to create several assets including, png, codesnippet block, html paste email and template. I tried creating a webpage type. Even though I received a 200 response, nothing happened and I read somewhere that it's not possible. Is it true that creating a webpage is not possible via the API? And if so, does anyone know if behind the scenes a webpage can be created through code? I would assume so since from the UI you can click a button and do it. That leads me to my next question. If we list it on AppExchange, does that open up additional functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you created was not an actual Cloudpage or microsite or landing page. What you created was essentially a content asset that can be used for a webpage. Currently everything involving Cloudpages or other items in Web Studio are not accessible publicly and all is handled by internal APIs that require a different authentication process to access.

Honestly, the APIs for webpages you can access through Content Builder are really only useful for retrieving and not really anything else.

To summarize, the only way to create a CloudPage or other similar webpage in SFMC is through the UI or somehow through gaining access to the internal API (which is not an easy nor a safe path to go down).

Comment: Thank you @Gortonington